# calling an Action using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, playframework

Fairly new to the PLAY Framework and because of restriction at my work we are using the 1.2.5 version, and while up til now was able to do all my process using the regular process from HTML to Controller via form submit. I would like to call an Application.Action from a JavaScript function.

While I have a form where information is inputted, another non-submit button could be clicked to go on a separate page for extra information. I want to call a JavaScript function via the "onClick" and inside the JavaScript function call the "@Application.Action(some param...)".

I need to get what is in a particular input field before calling the action.

I tried to do that with a PLAY "popup" but that does not seems to work as I can't pass the parameters along.

so here is the snippet I have:

in HTML file (extends the main.html who has all the javascript file "include")

```
 <form>....
        some input fields here
        submit button here
    </form>

<button onclick="myFunction()" data-role="button" style="width: 5em">Click here</button>
```

in the JavaScript file that is included in main.html I have something like this

```
function myFunction() {
    var inputField1 = document.getElementById('inputField1').value;
    var inputField2 = document.getElementById('inputField2').value;
    var inputField3 = document.getElementById('inputField3').value;
    window.location = "@{Application.moreInfo(inputField1, inputField2, inputField3)}";
}
```

Of course that does not work

Is there a way to do it like that?

Do I have to create a route for that?

I was able to reach a separate page by replacing

```
window.location = "@{Application.moreInfo(inputField1, inputField2, inputField3)}";
```

with

```
 window.location.href='/goThere';
```

as long as I have a route

```
 /goThere   Application.goThere
```

but I could not figure out a way to pass parameters, I tried to set the route like

```
/goThere/{inputField1}{inputField2}{inputField3}    Application.goThere(inputField1...)
```

but I guess I do not have the right syntax either.

Is there a way to call an Application.Action and pass it parameters/fields from a JavaScript function.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking.

Comment: This all can be done so easy with jQuery. Why you don't want to use it? http://jsfiddle.net/L8duC/

Comment: Clarification: in Play when using the form-controller-process you have  <form name="SomeEvent" action="@{Application.doStuff(someParam)}" method="GET">...</form> I want to be able to click on another button - onClick=myFunction() to show a different page and then callback that action from that new page @{Application.doStuff(someParam)} - hence How do you call an Application.Action from a JavaScript function

Comment: Bondye, I want to call a different page when click a non-submit button. There would be a submit button and a More Info button, when clicking the More Info button you go to a javascript function <do some precess> and call back Application.Action with all parameters

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`#{jsAction /}`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/tags#jsaction) template tag does exactly what you want.

Example:

Assume you have a route

```
GET     /moreinfo/{foo}/{bar}        Application.moreInfo
```

You can use the result of `jsAction` to get the correct URL with the parameters you want:

```
var fieldOne = "I'm a Javascript variable";
var fieldTwo = "Really? Me too";
var moreInfoAction = #{jsAction @Application.moreInfo(":foo", ":bar") /};

// and since it looks like you want to set the current location
// to your freshly obtained URL:
window.location.href = moreInfoAction({"foo": fieldOne, "bar": fieldTwo});
```